# Sending JSON from Plugin to template in a redirect?

Tags: templates, plugin, json, redirection

I have a plugin that loops through some code and builds an array of results then redirects the user to a results page. How can I pass the results to the redirected page without using the URL segment? The results can be converted to JSON if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse those variables! Then just dump them out in template tags.

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/template.html#parsing-variables

You use the template class to pass your variables through the EE template engine, then you can just make a loop out of your results in your template:

```
{exp:my_plugin parameterone="666"}
    A result:
    {result_array}
        {result_variable_one}
        {result_variable_two}
    {/result_array}
{/exp:my_plugin}
```